# Conditional expectation as a random integral

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I want to show the following: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra, $Z$ a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable and $Y$ a random variable independent of $\mathcal{G}$. Then for every non-negative measurable function $g$ we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[g(Y,Z) \vert  \mathcal{G}] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(y,Z) dP_{Y}(y).
$$

My attempt of the proof: The RHS is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, so it remains to show that
$$
\int_{A} g(Y(\omega),Z(\omega)) d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{A} \int_{y \in \mathbb{R}} g(y,Z(\omega)) dP_{Y}(y) d\mathbb{P}(\omega)
$$
for all $A \in \mathcal{G}$.

Now I would like to write $A = (Y,Z)^{-1}((Y,Z)(A))$ in order to apply the change of variables formula to the LHS, but this is only possible if $(Y,Z)$ is injective, which is not the case in general. How can I remove this issue? Assuming we have $A = (Y,Z)^{-1}((Y,Z)(A))$, the LHS equals (using independence)
$$
\int_{y \in Y(A)}  \int_{z \in Z(A)} g(y,z) dP_{Y}(y) dP_{Z}(z) \overset{(*)}{=} 
\int_{y \in Y(A)}  \int_{A} g(y,Z(\omega)) dP_{Y}(y) d\mathbb{P}(\omega).
$$
In $(*)$ I transformed $z \in Z(A)$ to $\omega \in A$ and I am not sure if this is correct and how to justify it if this is the case. Now the new LHS looks almost like the RHS but I am integrating over $y \in Y(A)$ instead of $y \in \mathbb{R}$, so what went wrong in my sloppy calculations?

Comment: A usual approach, which bypasses all your troubles, i to study the class $C$ of functions $g$ such that the identity holds. As is often the case in such situations, showing that $C$ contains some simple functions is direct (here, every $g(y,z)=h(y)k(z)$), showing that $C$ is stable by linear combinations is also direct, and that $C$ is stable by monotonous limits as well.  Thus $C$ contains "at least" every nonnegative integrable function $g$... which is the result you are after.

Comment: @Did Thank you. Of course, the standard machine, my bad! Starting with indicator functions $g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, consider $g = \mathbb{1}_{B}$ for some $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Then we have $g(Y,Z) = \mathbb{1}_{\{(Y,Z) \in B\}}$ and the LHS equals $\mathbb{P}(A \cap [(Y,Z) \in B])$.

Comment: Even better (as indicated in my comment): start with product functions.

Comment: Passing from simple functions to monotone limits, are product functions good enough? In the standard construction one allows arbitary sets in the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra. (In our case $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$)

Comment: Yes, for example because unions of disjoint products are enough to generate the Borel sigma-algebra on the product space.

Comment: Ok cool. Now I calculated that the RHS is equal to $\mathbb{P}(Y \in B_1)  \mathbb{P}(A \cap \{Z \in B_2\})$. The LHS equals $\mathbb{P}(A \cap \{Y \in B_1\} \cap \{Z \in B_2\})$. To conclude the statement we need that $A \cap \{Z \in B_2\}$ is independent of $\{Y \in B_1\}$. We know by assumption that $\sigma(Y)$ is independent of $\sigma(Z)$ and moreover $\sigma(Z) \subseteq \mathcal{G}$. But $A \cap \{Z \in B_2\} \in \mathcal{G}$ and we don't know if $\mathcal{G}$ is independent of $\sigma(Y)$ ... I think I overlook something here.

Comment: Hmmm, good catch, I guess I subconsciously replaced "and $Y$ a random variable independent of $Z$" by "and $Y$ a random variable independent of $\mathcal G$" when reading the phrase in your question. Of course the result fails if one only assumes that $Y$ is independent of $Z$.

Comment: Ok, I changed "independet of $Z$" to "independent of $\mathcal{G}$". Now I understood everything. Thank you for your time and your help.